# Is there a way to copy from excel to word without format getting changed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Is there a way to copy from excel to word without the format getting changed (for example if you use a size of 6 in excel, which is not supported for the same font in word)?

Currently I'm doing int this way that I copy in excel, put it into paint and then copy to word, but a more straight forward method would be VERY nice.

Comment: Are you trying to do a plain-text paste (ie. Take the _target_ formatting)?  Or do you want to keep the _source_ formatting?

Comment: The source formatting. As when I copy I always get the target formatting (except when I copy via paint but that is then an image anyway^^

Comment: What version is your Office/Word/Excel? 2007/2010/2013/2016?

Comment: Mostly 2013 version (strange thought I added the comment already hours ago oO).  But also interested generally in case there is no (or a minimal) difference between the versions.

Answer (score 4):

The closest I can find (using Office 2010; I'm not sure if it still works with newer versions) is to right-click your mouse, and under **Paste Options**:

[image]

look for the icon that looks like a clipboard overlaid with a picture of a paintbrush (this should be the left-hand icon in the picture above).

Comment: To add to this, you can quickly replicate this behavior via shortcuts by copying using `Ctrl-C` and pasting using `Ctrl-V`, then immediately letting go of `Ctrl` and pressing `M`. This behavior should work between all Office apps.

Answer (score 2):

These instructions are for Office 2010, but work exactly the same in Office 2013.

Make sure to set your Cut, Copy, and Paste settings in Word to keep source formatting for cross-program pasting. These settings are found under 'File > Options > Advanced > Cut, Copy, and Paste'.

[image: File > Options > Advanced > Cut, Copy, and Paste]

After you set these settings, it should allow you to keep formatting of text copied from excel. My example shows me copying a 3x3 grid of text set to Calibri size 6.

[image: Calibri, size 6]

Which pastes a wonderfully clean table into your word document in exactly the format you copied it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The are at least three options:

1. put the material in as a **Picture**
2. put the material in as a **Table**
3. put the material in as an **embedded Object**

**Picture** is a good way to preserve format.  It is easy to re-size and re-position a **Picture**.

In Excel, copy **As Picture** and then paste the Picture into your Word doc.

[image]